# IEEE 754 Floating point math operations

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point, biginteger

So for floating point operations, as I understand it, are derivatives of school-grade math.  Multiplication and division you either add or subtract the exponents after doing the calculation.  In performing my code design (on paper), I have ran into a few questions which I have listed below:

For addition and/or subtraction...

- How do you handle the case if both the bases and exponents are different?
- What if the difference in exponents is greater than the size of the biginteger data type?

I have found a few things online, but nothing that really spells out how deal with this.  Now from the school grade math, you have to normalize the values before you can run any calculations on them.

So...

2^3 + 3^2 = 8 + 9 = 17

Is the same thing required here?

EDIT: My apologies to the community for the confusion as I thought the question was quite specific.  This is using powers of 2 as the current platform is IA32.  I don't know of any platform that does floating point in decimal.  I was using decimal as an example.

The first question was answered by Mark B:

> Thankfully, floats are all done with powers of 2, so just normalize the exponent. e.g. using powers of 10 scientific notation.

So now the second question (as listed above) is what do you do when in order to normalize the value, the amount that you have to shift exceeds the space in the data type?  In other words, if I have say...32 bits of precision, and I have to shift...say 35 bits...to get the exponents to match, how do you handle that condition?  How does the FPU handle it?

Comment: IEEE floating-point numbers are always Base 2.  However, you can definitely run into problems if you try to represent a number larger (or smaller) than the datatype can hold.  It's just like trying to put a value of 256 into an 8-bit integer; it just doesn't fit.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this question because I'm not certain, but this may be the sort of thing mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ...  entire discussions can be had regarding how to handle floating point values.

Comment: @Lotharyx [Nope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#IEEE_754-2008), decimal formats are also specified.

Comment: I stand corrected regarding the IEEE spec, but does C and C++ make use of decimal floating point representations?  He's tagged his question with C and C++.

Comment: @Lotharyx neither language specify the floating point representation. I don't think I've ever used hardware that used a decimal representation.

Comment: Oh, good point, it would be hardware-dependent wouldn't it.

Comment: Read this paper: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1377)

Comment: YOu have too many questions. Asking even particular questions here will not give you the whole picture. OTOH, this is no tutorial site. How about doing some research about the basics first? There is enough information to be found by some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEE 754 floating point numbers are just an implementation of floating points. As usual, wikipedia has nice [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on it.

You choose a base (generally 2, but IEEE 754 also defines base 10), and a real number is then represented as f = sign * significand * base <sup>exponent</sup>, where significand, and exponent are both integers and sign it either i or -1. Specifically, you have:

> Finite numbers, which may be either base 2 (binary) or base 10 (decimal). Each finite number is described by three integers: s = a sign (zero or one), c = a significand (or 'coefficient'), q = an exponent. The numerical value of a finite number is
>         (−1)s × c × bq
>       where b is the base (2 or 10), also called radix. For example, if the base is 10, the sign is 1 (indicating negative), the significand is 12345, and the exponent is −3, then the value of the number is −11 × 12345 × 10−3 = −1 × 12345 × .001 = −12.345.
>
> Two infinities: +∞ and −∞.
>
> Two kinds of NaN: a quiet NaN (qNaN) and a signaling NaN (sNaN). A NaN may carry a payload that is intended for diagnostic information indicating the source of the NaN. The sign of a NaN has no meaning, but it may be predictable in some circumstances.
>
> The possible finite values that can be represented in a format are determined by the base b, the number of digits in the significand (precision p), and the exponent parameter emax:
>
> - c must be an integer in the range zero through bp−1 (e.g., if b=10 and p=7 then c is 0 through 9999999)
> - q must be an integer such that 1−emax ≤ q+p−1 ≤ emax (e.g., if p=7 and emax=96 then q is −101 through 90).
>
> Hence (for the example parameters) the smallest non-zero positive number that can be represented is 1×10−101 and the largest is 9999999×1090 (9.999999×1096), and the full range of numbers is −9.999999×1096 through 9.999999×1096. The numbers −b1−emax and b1−emax (here, −1×10−95 and 1×10−95) are the smallest (in magnitude) normal numbers; non-zero numbers between these smallest numbers are called subnormal numbers.
>
> Zero values are finite values with significand 0. These are signed zeros, the sign bit specifies if a zero is +0 (positive zero) or −0 (negative zero).

Please look at the referenced page for (many) more details...

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, floats are all done with powers of 2, so just normalize the exponent. e.g. using powers of 10 scientific notation:

```
   3.1e5        0.031e7
+ 2.96e7  ->  + 2.96 e7  
--------        -------
                2.991e7
```